# Problem with constexpr keyword with classes

Tags: c++, oop

So I recently saw this snippet on the internet:

```cpp
class Human
{
    int age;

public:
    constexpr Human(int humansAge) : age(humansAge) {}
    constexpr int GetAge() const { return age; }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    constexpr Human somePerson(15);
    const int hisAge = somePerson.GetAge();

    return 0;
}
```

Now I've compared this class with and without the keyword `constexpr` on compiler explorer and I saw that the constructor didn't have it's instructions on the right side, but the function `GetAge` had them, Now I have some questions:

1. What is `constexpr` doing here to the constructor and the function `GetAge`?
2. What is the role of the `const` keyword after the prototype of GetAge(), does it mean that age will be returned as a const?
3. What happens if I declare `int hisAge` as not being a const?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "The constexpr specifier declares that it is possible to evaluate the value of the function or variable at compile time." -- [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)

Comment: 2. that const means something like `const this`

Comment: 3. see 2 (padding)

Comment: Thank you for your response @appleapple, however could you post this as an answer, and also I don't understand your answer to my first question and what does `const this` mean? Thank you.

Comment: @ Alex I've write a(little) more detailed answer.

Comment: @appleapple ok, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two separate questions here: `const` and `constexpr`.

Let's start with `const`, stripping out the `constexpr`.

```
class Human
{
    int age;

public:
    Human(int humansAge) : age(humansAge) {}
    int GetAge() const { return age; }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Human somePerson(15);
    const int hisAge = somePerson.GetAge();

    return 0;
}
```

The `const` on `GetAge()` declares that  calling `GetAge()` will not change the state of the object. Thus if we tried to write:

```
int GetAge() const { return ++age; }
```

it would cause a compilation error, which would not be there without the `const`.

The const on `hisAge`:

```
const int hisAge = ...
```

simply says that hisAge can't be changed after it's been initialized, so a subsequent

```
hisAge = 50;
```

would be illegal.

However, all these are runtime constants. Although we've initialized human with a hard-coded `15`, this would equally have worked with a value read in from the user or a file.

If we reintroduce all the `constexpr` keywords, it means we now have compile-time constants. We can have multiple humans with different ages, but all the ages must be available at compile time, i.e. hard-coded.

Comment: `constexpr` doesn't **force** constant in this case. It's still a hint afaict.

Comment: Thank you very much! Really useful response!

Answer (score 1):

1 .  The constexpr specifier declares that *it is possible* to evaluate the value of the function or variable at compile time. -- [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr).

I'd say it does nothing in your example.

---

2 . `constexpr int GetAge() const { return age; }`

that `const` means something like `this` is `const Human` (`const Human this` <=> `const int x`)

---

3 . What happens if I declare `int hisAge` as not being a `const`?

[It'd change nothing](https://godbolt.org/z/G3W8qc).

---

`const` is *almost* a hint, it helps you (programmer) write const-correctness code, stop you from unintended modification of state. It may change where the variable locates or some compiler optimization, but you'd probably not notice the difference.